# cocoa CollectionView button action

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, collectionview

I made a horizontal NScollectionView with forward and back buttons, but when I click on the buttons the items in the collection do not move?

In the button action I have inserted the scrollToVisible method but I think something is still missing.

Maybe an NSScrollView extension is missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4vtZ.png)

The @IBAction buttons are connected to the two left and right side arrows

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var availableUsers = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5", "User6", "User7", "User8", "User9"]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLeft: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonRight: NSButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        configureCollectionView()
        
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
     
        }
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return availableUsers.count
        
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        
      let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
        
        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CollectionViewItem else {
            return item
        }
        
        collectionViewItem.labelNew.stringValue = self.availableUsers[indexPath.item]
        
        collectionViewItem.viewNew.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        
        return item
        
    }
 
    @IBAction func buttonLeft(_ sender: Any) {
        collectionView.scrollToVisible(collectionView.visibleRect.offsetBy(dx: -100, dy: 0))
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonRight(_ sender: Any) {
        collectionView.scrollToVisible(collectionView.visibleRect.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 0))
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView() {

      let flowLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
      flowLayout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 160.0, height: 160.0)
      flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
      flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
      collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

      view.wantsLayer = true
      collectionView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor

    }



}
```

Comment: "what is missing in my code"  You aren't telling to which those IBAction connections are made.

Comment: @ElTomato The IBAction buttons are connected to the two left and right side arrows

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase my statement.  Let us know under which class those IBActions are being used.

Comment: Is the scroll direction horizontal (question and scroll code) or vertical (image)?

Comment: I solved it by putting: flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal but I can't hide the scroll bar.